# Case of SD card file names different between OSX Finder and terminal

Tags: java, macos, finder

I have a single case of a directory name not having the same has on the console as in Finder (see screen shot).
[image]
It's the folder "private" (or "PRIVATE" on the shell).
I ran into this while debugging a software problem in a Java application. It's weird that I am not able to create a directory on that same device with Java that exhibits the same behaviour. What the heck is going on here?

Comment: Nasty case-folding in the OS X filesystem.

Comment: Meaning what exactly? Why am I not able to create a directory on that card that behaves the same way with any of the tools I have?